# Pull from Cassandra database whenever any new rows or any new update is there?

Tags: java, triggers, cassandra, apache-zookeeper

I am working on a system in which I need to store Avro Schemas in Cassandra database. So in Cassandra we will be storing something like this

```
SchemaId            AvroSchema

1                   some schema
2                   another schema
```

Now suppose as soon as I insert another row in the above table in Cassandra and now the table is like this -

```
SchemaId            AvroSchema

1                   some schema
2                   another schema
3                   another new schema
```

As soon as I insert a new row in the above table - I need to tell my Java program to go and pull the new schema id and corresponding schema..

What is the right way to solve these kind of problem?

**I know, one way is to have polling every few minutes, let's say every 5 minutes we will go and pull the data from the above table but this is not the right way to solve this problem as every 5 minutes, I am doing a pull whether or not there are any new schemas..**

But is there any other solution apart from this?

Can we use Apache Zookeeper? Or Zookeeper is not fit for this problem? 
Or any other solution?

I am running Apache Cassandra 1.2.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some solutions:

- With database triggers:  Cassandra 2.0 has some trigger support but it looks like it is not final and might change a little in 2.1 according to this article:  http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-0-prototype-triggers-support.  Triggers are a common solution.
- You brought up polling but that is not always a bad option. Especially if you have something that marks that row as not being pulled yet, so you can just pull the new rows out of Cassandra.   Pulling once every 5 minutes is nothing load wise for Cassandra or any database if the query is not a heavy cost.  This option might not be good if new rows get inserted on a very infrequent basis.

Zookeeper would not be a perfect solution, see this quote:

> Because watches are one time triggers and there is latency between
>   getting the event and sending a new request to get a watch you cannot
>   reliably see every change that happens to a node in ZooKeeper. Be
>   prepared to handle the case where the znode changes multiple times
>   between getting the event and setting the watch again. (You may not
>   care, but at least realize it may happen.)

Quote sourced from: http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.2/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_WatchRememberThese

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.. So according to you, polling option is much better in my use case? And there is no other option that I can use? Thanks for the help...

Comment: I don't know all the factors in your use case, but based on what I have heard so far, polling isn't an option that should be written off yet.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra 3.0

You can use this and it will get you everything in the insert as a json object.

```
public class HelloWorld implements ITrigger
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);

    public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition partition)
    {
        String tableName = partition.metadata().cfName;
        logger.info("Table: " + tableName);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("message_id", partition.metadata().getKeyValidator().getString(partition.partitionKey().getKey()));

        try {
            UnfilteredRowIterator it = partition.unfilteredIterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Unfiltered un = it.next();
                Clustering clt = (Clustering) un.clustering();  
                Iterator<Cell> cells = partition.getRow(clt).cells().iterator();
                Iterator<ColumnDefinition> columns = partition.getRow(clt).columns().iterator();

                while(columns.hasNext()){
                    ColumnDefinition columnDef = columns.next();
                    Cell cell = cells.next();
                    String data = new String(cell.value().array()); // If cell type is text
                    obj.put(columnDef.toString(), data);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        logger.debug(obj.toString());

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have made a repository for this which can be used to create a new project and ant build file to execute. Contact me for any more help.

https://github.com/amritsinghbains/cassandra-trigger