# insert update delete trigger on cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am learning `cassandra`..

First question I want to know that is it important to include any other package class like java package included in trigger to run a trigger in `cassandra`.

I want to data **synchronize** in `cassandra` between two tables. I searched all over the web but there isn't any specific solution to my question.

I have two tables. with any detla(change) in the first table all the data from first table should be so syncronized that with any insert update or delete on 1st table the change should reflect on the second table also.

Please help me with the query.

Clock sychronization is also welcome

Comment: Please only apply tags that are relevant to your question. If you think you are getting more exposure by including other tags, then trust me that it's not the kind of attention you really want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573002/pull-from-cassandra-database-whenever-any-new-rows-or-any-new-update-is-there/39496648#39496648

Answer (score 0):

> First question I want to know that is it important to include any other package class like java package included in trigger to run a trigger in cassandra

Don't use trigger, **unless you know very well the internal plumbing of Cassandra write path**. Otherwise you'll break your cluster

For synchronization between 2 tables, many solutions:

- use Materialized Views if the 2nd table is a denormalization of the 1st table
- on the client side, write to the 1st table and write the changes/updates to the 2nd table and use LOGGED BATCH

Comment: Thanks doanduyhai. Can you illustrate me how to use LOGGED BATCH.