# Get column name and their value in cassandra trigger

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql

I have this cassandra trigger

```
public class AuditTrigger implements ITrigger
{

private Properties properties = loadProperties();

public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition update)
{
    String auditKeyspace = properties.getProperty("keyspace");
    String auditTable = properties.getProperty("table");

    RowUpdateBuilder audit = new RowUpdateBuilder(Schema.instance.getCFMetaData(auditKeyspace, auditTable),
                                                  FBUtilities.timestampMicros(),
                                                  UUIDGen.getTimeUUID());
    audit.add("keyspace_name", update.metadata().ksName);
    audit.add("table_name", update.metadata().cfName);
    audit.add("primary_key", update.metadata().getKeyValidator().getString(update.partitionKey().getKey()));

    return Collections.singletonList(audit.build());
}
}
```

ho can I get the inserted value and their column name ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573002/pull-from-cassandra-database-whenever-any-new-rows-or-any-new-update-is-there/39496648#39496648